# Struggling in the last part of my solution for a geometry question.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

The question is as follows:

> Let $(a_1,b_1)$ and $Q(a_2,b_2)$ be two distinct points on a circle with center $C(√2 , √3)$. Let $O$ be the origin and $OC$ be perpendicular to both $CP$ and $CQ$. If the area of the triangle $OCP$ is  $\sqrt 35 /2$ ,then  $a_1^2 + a_2^2 + b_2^2 + b_2^2$ is equal to _____.

And here is my solution:
[image: Diagram]

Since OC - OP, and OC - OQ meet perpendicular to each other, PQ must form a straight line. Since C is the center, $\Delta OCP = \Delta OCQ$. Using distance formula, we can say that:
$$PC = \sqrt 5$$

Since OPQ form a triangle of area $\sqrt 35$,we can say that:
$$\sqrt 35 = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt 5 \sqrt {(a_1^2 - a_2^2) + (b_1^2 - b_2^2)}$$
$$28 = (a_1^2 - a_2^2) + (b_1^2 - b_2^2)$$
$$ 28 = a_1^2 + a_2^2 + b_1^2 + b_2^2 - 2(a_1a_2+b_1b_2)$$

But the answer turns out to be $a_1^2 + a_2^2 + b_1^2 + b_2^2 = 24$. So it must be sufficient for me to prove that $a_1a_2 + b_1b_2$ is equal 2. But don't see how I can. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Radius of circle is $~\dfrac{\sqrt{35}}{\sqrt{5}}.$

Comment: @user2661923 Hmm yes!, and you would find OP and OQ, where OP^2 + QP^2 will give the result I want. However I was hoping to find it in an alternate method, and hence I came this route!

Comment: An alternate approach is fine, except that you have to be careful of arithmetic mistakes.  If my computation of the radius of the circle is accurate, and if that computation leads to a specific answer, then that answer must be accurate. Then if an alternative approach leads to an alternate computation, then either the alternative approach is invalid, or there is an arithmetic mistake in the computation around the alternative approach.

Comment: Hmm often, the simplest route gives the perfect answer, and since it involves the least steps, there is also a lesser risk of things going wrong. That's what I learnt today I guess.  Thanks for your input!

Comment: I suggest that you *also* find the mistake in your alternate approach, to enhance your understanding.  Is the mistake that the approach is invalid, or is the mistake an arithmetic mistake?

Comment: @user2661923 Yes definitely!